# ElectronJs with AngularJs: Cookies are not holding values if application is restarted

Tags: angularjs, cookies, chromium, electron

I am learning [ElectronJs](http://electron.atom.io) so I have started with making a simple [AngularJs](https://angularjs.org/) application with it and here I started stumbling.

I want to store some persistent data like user token and email id and so on. So, in order to do this, I am using `$cookieStore`.

The given below example is working fine in (firefox, chrome) browser but when I am running the same example in electron browser window then it's storing the values temporarily and losing the values at the time of restart.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.1/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AngularJS Cookies Example</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyController">
    {{platformCookie}} {{myFruit}} {{myFlower}}

    <input type="button" value="setCookie" ng-click="setCookie()" />
    <input type="button" value="getCookie" ng-click="getCookie()" />

    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies']);

        myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$cookies', '$cookieStore', 
        function($scope, $cookies, $cookieStore) {
            $cookies.userName = 'Vikas';

            $scope.setCookie = function()
            {
                $scope.platformCookie = $cookies.userName;
                $cookieStore.put('fruit', 'Apple');
                $cookieStore.put('flower', 'Rose');



                console.log('set cookies');
            }

            $scope.getCookie = function()
            {
                $scope.myFruit = $cookieStore.get('fruit');
                $scope.myFlower = $cookieStore.get('flower');

                console.log($scope.myFruit);
            }

        }]);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT**
[Electron Session](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/session.md#class-session)

I have also tried to use Electron Session in order to create persistent cookies, however, its also not working and getting disposed on the application restart.

code:

```
const session = require('electron').session;
const ses = session.fromPartition('persist:name');

 // Query all cookies associated with a specific URL.
    ses.cookies.get({ url: 'http://www.github.com' }, (error, cookies) => {
        console.log(cookies);
    });

    // Set a cookie with the given cookie data;
    // may overwrite equivalent cookies if they exist.
    const cookie = { url: 'http://www.github.com', name: 'dummy_name', value: 'dummy' };
    ses.cookies.set(cookie, (error) => {
        if (error)
            console.error(error);
    });
```

using this code when you run the application second time it should display the cookies data that had been set but no luck.

Comment: Electron doesn't persist session info by default: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/session.md#class-session

Comment: @DanielBeck as you recommended I used the `session` but its not working as well for persistent cookies. Please check the edit in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies are not persistent if you do not give them `expirationDate`

```
let cookie = {
            url: 'http://www.drutas.com',
            name: 'userDetailsGoogle',
            value: JSON.stringify(userDetailsGoogle),
            expirationDate: 2093792393999
        };
```

If you give them `expirationDate` then cookies will persist